# Selectively Bring Data to the DropDownList and Bring All Other Data Sametime

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selected

I am saving city and town information to the user table while the user is registering. What I want to do is: When user goes to the user profile edit page, I want the city and the town to be seen DropDownList selectively, but at the same time I want to fill in the DropDownList for all the other data in the city and town table. For example: When I registered I chose Portland as city and I chose Hood River as town. And I want these two to come as an selected, but I want to list all other towns and cities in same dropdown.

This is my where I took the city and town information in the user table:

```
private void GetUserCityAndTown()
{
    if(Session["userid"] != null)
    {
        DataRow dr = function.GetDataRow("SELECT city.name, town.name FROM kullanici LEFT JOIN city on city.city_no = user.city LEFT JOIN town on town.town_no = user.town WHERE userid=" + Session["userid"].ToString());
        if (dr != null)
        {
            DrpDwnLstCity.Text = dr[0].ToString();
            DrpDwnLstTown.Text = dr[1].ToString();
        }
}
```

And this is where I took all the city information from city table:

```
private void GetCity()
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aytasarimConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM city", conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        DrpDwnLstCity.DataSource = reader;
        DrpDwnLstCity.DataValueField = "city_no";
        DrpDwnLstCity.DataTextField = "name";
        DrpDwnLstCity.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        string message = "<script>alert('Error!');</script>";
        Response.Write(message);
    }
}
```

And this is where I took all the town information from the town table:

```
private void GetTown()
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aytasarimConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM town WHERE city_no='" + DrpDwnLstCity.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        DrpDwnLstTown.DataSource = reader;
        DrpDwnLstTown.DataValueField = "town_no";
        DrpDwnLstTown.DataTextField = "name";
        DrpDwnLstTown.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        string message = "<script>alert('Error!');</script>";
        Response.Write(message);
    }
}

protected void DrpDwnLstCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetTown();
}
```

Where do i make mistakes? Should I use something like that to bring DropDownList selected:

```
DrpDwnLstCity.Items.FindByValue(dr["city_no"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

Comment: What does your code do now? What do you want it to do?

Comment: What I want to do is, for example: When I registered, I chose Portland as city and I chose Hood River as town (I am saving these 2 information in the user table as number). And I want these two to come as an selected when I go to profile.aspx, but I want to list all other towns and cities in same dropdown.

Comment: And what does your code do now?

Comment: My code doing: Only the data in the city and town table is listed in my DropDowns.

Comment: i think you should add `DrpDwnLstCity.Items.FindByValue(dr["city_no"].ToString()).Selected = true;` this code to select a value from `dropdownlist`.

Comment: I've try this but still I get an error. I don't know why.